# Get Gas use of a transaction with web3

Tags: web3.py, ganache

is it possible to get the information about the actual amount of gas that was used for a transaction? I have the transaction hash and I'd like to know the gas that was used by this transaction after the block has been mined. The estimate Gas won't be helpful for me.
I'm using web3.py and Ganache

Comment: `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` will have the gas used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait for the receipt and read the `gasUsed` value, like so:

```
from web3.auto import w3

transaction_hash = '0x...'
receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(transaction_hash)
print(receipt.gasUsed)
```

Naturally, you may have to set up your `Web3` instance with different connection parameters. The auto import is just shorthand for a quick and dirty setup.

> If I have multiple transactions in one Block, this will return the gasUsed up to this transactions.

*(from a comment on another answer)*

It seems you were looking at `cumulativeGasUsed`, which tracks all gas used in the block. `gasUsed` will be the gas from only that transaction.

Comment: weird, i did use gasUsed... is it possible that bc of Ganache I get a different output?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is a `gasUsed` bug in ganache. Check out if this is the same issue you were seeing: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/445

Answer (score 1):

after send transaction, you can use Eth.waitForTransactionReceipt to get tx receipt. when you get receipt, "gasUsed" is real gas used in tx.

[Eth.waitForTransactionReceipt](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.waitForTransactionReceipt)

Comment: thank you! but if I have multiple transactions in one Block, this will return the gasUsed up to this transactions. So if I have for example 5 transactions in one Block and I look up the 3rd transaction of the block the gasUsed variable will give me the gas that has been used for the transactions 1 + 2 + 3. So if I only wanna have the gas for the 3rd transaction, do i have to calculate it myself?